# "Illegal base64 character 3" with sent integer across TCP connection (AES Encrypted String)

Tags: java, encryption, tcp, base64, illegalargumentexception

I have the following integer being sent across TCP: `3964956`

Sender Code:

```java
writer.write(Aes.encrypt(new String(file.length() + ""), node.getEncryptionKey()) + "\n");
writer.flush();
```

Receiver Code:

```java
String size;
if ((size = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if ((size = Aes.decrypt(size, node.getEncryptionKey())) == null) throw new Exception("decrypt err"); // <---
          // ERROR IS ABOVE LINE

    final long byteSize = Long.parseLong(size);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[5 * 1024];
```

Exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3`
The exception is being thrown when the reciever gets tries to decrypt the packet, the code for the actual encryption is below.

Encryption Class (Aes.java):

```java
    /***
     * Encrypt a String using AES.
     *
     * @param strToEncrypt The target String to encrypt
     * @param secret The secret key you wish to encrypt
     *               the String with, this secret key
     *               will be used to decrypt the String
     * @return The encrypted String
     */
    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret) throws Exception {
        setKey(secret);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }

    /***
     * Decrypt the AES Encrypted String.
     *
     * @param strToDecrypt The target String to decrypt
     * @param secret The secret key that was used to encrypt this String
     * @return The decrypted String
     */
    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) throws Exception {
        setKey(secret);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
    }
```

EDIT: More Code Below; there is a whole authentication process that is sequenced before the specific integer send specified above, all data uses the same AES encryption, however the data is not throwing any errors like the current one.

The Socket Objects

```java
try(InputStream is = socket.getInputStream(); BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())); BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))){
...
}
```

The function for receiving the Integer:

```java
processStreamsForDownload(cdn_node, reader, response.getOutputStream(), is);
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give a better answer since lots of code missing.

I just used posted code and filled up the missing gaps and it worked. (Secret key algorithm: `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256`; `PipedReader` and `PipedWriter` as `Reader` and `Writer`)

Would have been better to post a complete sample... Anyway try to isolate the problem, for example, first try to encrypt something and decrypt the result *directly* to check if that is working correctly. Next print out what is being send and what is being received (my guess is that data sent is not same as received).

<sub>obviously not the direct answer, but it should show a possible way to find the problem for given information in question.</sub>